# Is there a way to determine the length of edges in images under edge detection algorithms using OpenCV?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I am relatively new to OpenCV, but I have a question. I am interested in trying to figure out a way to take my image that have already been implemented by a color quantization algorithm and determine how often one color interacts with another.

For the case of two colors like the Facebook logo, I am interested in finding the 'perimeter' of 'f' since the white and blue pixels interact with each other on those edges.

How about cases like the FedEx logo, where I need to determine how often purple interacts with orange, purple interacts with white, and orange interacts with white. How can I determine the lengths of those edges?

I would like these edges to be represented in pixel lengths if possible. I am sure there is a way to mathematically study the associated image matrix and determine the pixel length of those edges, but I am curious if there is any functionality in the OpenCV package that would automate this process for me.

Using OpenCV and scikit-learn, I was able to determine the dominant colors of a logo in terms of RGB so this information is known so far. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Find contours on the image having edges, and find the perimeter of the contours using `cv2.arcLength()` function

Comment: Ahh thank you. Do you know if you can distinguish the contours between different pairs of colors by using this method?

Comment: This method can get you the length of each contour. It only works with binary images not with color images....

Comment: @JeruLuke: the OP wants the length common to two regions of given colors. arcLength won't do.

Comment: @JeruLuke Hi, i got a answer for this how to find edge length and using that i also found the angle between edges this answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67909421/how-to-get-length-of-each-side-of-a-shape-in-an-image now i am facing difficulty in representing edge length and corner angle as https://imgur.com/a/e2CVGxA , any help will be appreciated tried a lot but not able to get a answer .