# How to get length of each side of a shape in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Suppose we have an image as below:

[image: Input]

I want to determine the number of sides, and the length of each side.

Here in the image, we have three edges as straight lines, and the upper one is a curved edge. I am able to find the length of the three straight edges using Canny edge detection. We can have four vertices coordinates, and we can calculate the length of the three straight edges/lines, but unable to find the length of the curved edge.

[find number of sides python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67874570/) This is a good answer for getting the number of edges in an image, and we get the coordinates of vertices through the code in the above link. Further to get the length of the sides using the coordinates, we can use below code to get the length, if the edges are straight lines:

```
for pt in zip(points,np.roll(points,-1,0)):
#     print( pt )
    x = pt[0][0]
    y = pt[1][0]
    d = math.sqrt((x[1]-y[1])*(x[1]-y[1]) + (x[0]-y[0])*(x[0]-y[0]))
    print('length between point:',x,'and', y,'is', d)
```

To simplify my question: I want to find, how many edges/sides are there for a shape in an image, and their respective lengths, if the image shape has any curved sides.

Comment: I suggest posting a [mre] of what you have done so far.

Comment: Your image link is gone. For future visitors, could you please fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My idea would be to get the contour of the shape, try to detect "corners", e.g. using [Harris corner detection](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d0d/tutorial_py_features_harris.html), find matching points from the contour, and piecewise calculate the length of the edges using [`cv2.arcLength`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8d26483c636be6b35c3ec6335798a47c).

The input for the below `extract_and_measure_edges` method needs some binarized contour image like that one derived from your actual input image:

[image: Input]

So, the pre-processing must be adapted to the input images, and is out of scope of my answer! In the below code, the pre-processing is for the given input image, not for the two other examples.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def extract_and_measure_edges(img_bin):

    # Detect possible corners, and extract candidates
    dst = cv2.cornerHarris(img_bin, 2, 3, 0.04)
    cand = []
    for i, c in enumerate(np.argwhere(dst > 0.1 * np.max(dst)).tolist()):
        c = np.flip(np.array(c))
        if len(cand) == 0:
            cand.append(c)
        else:
            add = True
            for j, d in enumerate(cand):
                d = np.array(d)
                if np.linalg.norm(c - d) < 5:
                    add = False
                    break
            if add:
                cand.append(c)

    # Get indices of actual, nearest matching contour points
    corners = sorted([np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(c - cnt.squeeze(), axis=1))
                      for c in cand])

    # Extract edges from contour, and measure their lengths
    output = cv2.cvtColor(np.zeros_like(img_bin), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    for i_c, c in enumerate(corners):
        if i_c == len(corners) - 1:
            edge = np.vstack([cnt[c:, ...], cnt[0:corners[0], ...]])
        else:
            edge = cnt[c:corners[i_c + 1], ...]

        loc = tuple(np.mean(edge.squeeze(), axis=0, dtype=int).tolist())
        color = tuple(np.random.randint(0, 255, 3).tolist())
        length = cv2.arcLength(edge, False)
        cv2.polylines(output, [edge], False, color, 2)
        cv2.putText(output, '{:.2f}'.format(length), loc, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, color, 1)
    return output


# Read and pre-process image, extract contour of shape
# TODO: MODIFY TO FIT YOUR INPUT IMAGES
img = cv2.imread('2B2m4.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.threshold(gray, 16, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(thr, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
thr = cv2.drawContours(np.zeros_like(thr), [cnt], -1, 255, 1)

# Extract and measure edges, and visualize output
out = extract_and_measure_edges(thr)
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 6))
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1), plt.imshow(img), plt.title('Original input image')
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2), plt.imshow(thr, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Contour needed')
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3), plt.imshow(out), plt.title('Results')
plt.tight_layout(), plt.show()
```

That's the output:

[image: Output #1]

Example #2:

[image: Example #2]

Output:

[image: Output #2]

Example #3:

[image: Example #3]

Output:

[image: Output #3]

(I haven't paid attention to the correct color ordering...)

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
Matplotlib:    3.4.2
NumPy:         1.19.5
OpenCV:        4.5.2
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation , can we get the the number of vertex/corner and their angle ..as we have used cornerHarris ..can we modify the same piece of code to get that .
Thanks

Comment: Number of **found** vertices/corners would simply be `len(cand)` or `len(final)` for example. Regarding the angles, I don't think you'll able to derive that information from any of the existing code. You'd need to put (much) more effort in that, I'm afraid, especially, if you want to derive an angle between a straight line and some curvy edge.

Comment: ya that is a difficult task there..these vallue of edges we get are pixel values can we add another snippet for calibration in same piece of code , where a square object is given with known side of unit size... given which number of pixel per unit size is calculated

Comment: Of course, **you** can add such code. But you'll need to place that object next to your shape. Therefore, **you** need to distinguish between both objects, etc. That's a lot of modifications, **you** need to apply.

Comment: Hi , i was trying to get radius of those side which is curved/arc shape . Is it possible.
1. Identify whether the sides are straight line or curved shape
2. If curved shape want to get the radius for that

Comment: @HansHirse Nice answer , can you explain the for loop which is quoted in next line .  ( for i_c, c in enumerate(corners):if i_c == len(corners) - 1:
            edge = np.vstack([cnt[c:, ...], cnt[0:corners[0], ...]])
        else:
            edge = cnt[c:corners[i_c + 1], ...]

        loc = tuple(np.mean(edge.squeeze(), axis=0, dtype=int).tolist()))

Comment: Each `c` (corner) is an index to an element of the actual contour, something like this: `... - (x, y) - (c2x, c2y) - (x, y) - ... - (x, y) - (c3x, c3y) - (x, y) - ...`. With `cnt[c:corners[i_c + 1]`, you just select all elements from the actual contour between two corners, e.g. every point between `(c2x, c2y)` and `(c3x, c3y)`. There's a special case for the last corner, since contour elements won't necessarily start at a corner. So, `edge` is just a part of the contour `cnt`, corresponding to the current edge. The `loc` (text location) is just for the debug text output.

Comment: @HansHirse Thanks for your response with the hep of this code i am to find corner angle and edge length now want to represent edge length and corner angle as https://imgur.com/a/e2CVGxA but not able to represent it like this any help will really appreciated please help it will b great help .Thanks in advance