# Is there a simple way to extract the (x, y) pixel positions from outside curves in an image using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image of a tube as shown below, and I need to extract the (x, y) pixel positions for all 4 edges in SEPARATE lists, meaning one list for the left edge pixels, one list for the right edge pixels, etc.

If I just needed to find all the edges in one list that would be trivial by looping over the image, however, I can't find an appropriate method for splitting up this data collection. Thank you.

[image: [Tube][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrImu.jpg]

Comment: Concept: Get the four corners using either cv2.goodFeatures2Match(), or cv2.approxPolyDP(). Then get the contours and use np.argwhere() to get the y,x coordinates along the contour. Then use the corners to separate the points into 4 lists.

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you so much for the suggestion that seems like a great approach. I'll try that out now.

Comment: Also if this approach gives good results, please share it as answer in this question.

Comment: The idea from @fmw42 comment was kind of implemented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67917184/11089932 The creation of each `edge` is likely what you want to have.

Comment: @HansHirse Thank you very much for that link that code is extremely helpful.